How to Improve Mesh update times with Bevy, WGPU, and WGSL
My Goal
I am trying to make a terrain system with a LOD system using a modified surface nets algorithm. I build the terrain using a voxel octree which makes updating the terrain from player movement, etc very fast. It also means that lots of meshes have to be updated because the LOD system changes each chunk mesh. Calculating these updates is quite fast, but applying them seems to cause lag spikes.
The Problem
Currently, I apply every change in one frame. I do this in a function that simply calculates the changes that need to be made on a background thread and then applies all of those changes in the same frame that it finishes calculating them. That function does not cause the lag, but that same frame takes noticeably longer. I would like to get rid of this lag spike.
Two Sources
I have identified two places that could be causing lag, but I am still learning Bevy and WGPU, so I'm looking for some expert advice.
The first potential lag source is some bookkeeping Bevy does. I discovered that Bevy generates AABBs automatically for meshes. By generating those AABBs myself on a background thread, the lag is significantly reduced. Are there any other process that Bevy does that I could do myself on the background thread instead?
The second potential lag source is the shader. As part of texturing I ship in the shader a uniform to several array textures and their samplers. These array textures are effectively global to all terrain meshes, but I believe the default behavior is to send one copy per instance. Again I'm new to WGPU, etc. Because each mesh is built from quads using the surface nets algorithm, I also ship texture information in the quads.
Here's what I do: I send a color with each vertex. I decompose that color into a quad-space uv and a quad index. I index into a runtime-sized storage buffer of quads with that index, where each quad contains the material index for its corners. I use that index to reach into another runtime-sized storage buffer of materials. Currently these materials are local to each mesh to make each buffer as small as possible, but I could change this. Each material contains the indexes to various textures in the array textures I mentioned earlier. I'm skipping some unimportant details, but this is how I texture the terrain.
My suspicion is that either these storage buffers and/or the array textures being bound to each mesh's shader individually could be causing the lag. Is there a way to make some of these uniforms/array textures "global" to every terrain mesh and would that help? And Is there a better alternative to runtime-sized storage buffers for my quad and local material data? Keeping in mind I don't know how many quads/local materials there will be in any chunk mesh, and rounding up for a compile-time-sized uniform buffer seems wasteful. Last, would it help to make the materials buffer global (and larger) instead of local (many small buffers) like it is now?
I'm still quite new to shader stuff, etc, so I apologize for any misused terminology, etc. Hopefully my question makes sense.
